# Problems with Char in C

Tags: c

So I'm having a problem with the following code and I keep getting a runtime error when I compile it.  Essentially, this is a program to enter an undetermined amount of students and each student's undetermined amount of test scores, then calculate each student's GPA and display it back to the user.  The sample input I used was as follows:
Johnny
A
B

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char StudentName[50];
    char UserInput;
    int GradeSum;
    int TotalGrades;
    float GPA;
    int Test;
    int Try;

    Test = 0;

    while ( Test != 1 )
    {
        printf ("Enter the student’s name...\n");
        scanf ("%49s", StudentName);
        Try = strcmp(StudentName, "");
        if (Try != 0)
        {
            GradeSum = 0;
            TotalGrades = 0;
            GPA = 0;

            while ( Test != 1 )
            {
                printf ("Enter the student’s letter grade...\n");
                scanf (" %c", &UserInput);
                if ((UserInput == 'A') || (UserInput == 'B') || (UserInput == 'C') || (UserInput == 'D') || (UserInput == 'F'))
                {
                    if (UserInput == 'A')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 4;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }       
                    else if (UserInput == 'B')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 3;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }           
                    else if (UserInput == 'C')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 2;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }           
                    else if (UserInput == 'D')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 1;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }           
                    else if (UserInput == 'F')
                    {
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf ("That is not a valid letter grade...\n");
                }
            }
            GPA = ((float)GradeSum) / TotalGrades;
            printf ("%s: %f\n", StudentName, GPA);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I made the adjustments suggested to me and I'm still getting a Runtime Error and the output looks like this:

```
Enter the student’s name...
Enter the student’s letter grade...
Enter the student’s letter grade...
Enter the student’s letter grade...
Enter the student’s letter grade...
Enter the student’s letter grade...
Enter the student’s letter grade...
```

And it just keeps going on and on like that...

Comment: It just says "Runtime error" and doesn't give any specifics

Comment: Assuming you're using GCC, compile with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.  In addition to Sourav Ghosh's advice, that is.

Comment: I'm using an online compiler.  Two actually; CodeChef and Ideone

Comment: That's definitely worth noting in your question then :) Most people around here probably use GCC or Clang or Visual Studio to compile C, so an online compiler is going to give very different errors messages than people would expect!

Comment: My apologies.  I'm fairly new to StackOverflow

Comment: No worries - welcome to the community! We're happy to have you here :)

Comment: re. the edit, what input are you entering

Comment: Same input, Johnny A B

Comment: Your inner `while ( Test != 1 )` loop is an infinite loop: you never set `Test` within it, and you don't have any exit conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, instead of

```
 scanf ("%s", &StudentName);
```

adding

```
scanf ("%49s", StudentName);
```

will suffice.

Then, the content of an array cannot be compared using the `==` operator. You need to make use of [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for that.

After that, change

```
 scanf ("%c", &UserInput);
```

to

```
 scanf (" %c", &UserInput);
```

to avoid the previously stored newline.

Finally, to enforce the floating-point division, you can use a cast, like

```
 GPA = ((float)GradeSum) / TotalGrades;
```

Comment: I appreciate your rapid response.  As far as using strcmp, can I replace the < if ( UserInput != '' ) > with < var = strcmp ( UserInput, "" ); if (var != 0 ) ... >?

Comment: @PorkchopDonut  I don't think so ,`strcmp` require string and your variable is a character .

Comment: @PorkchopDonut [This might help you in the future to format your code better in comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) The page also contains more editing help for questions/answers, which allows more formatting. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The edits made, fixed the problem for me, no run-time errors at all....

```
 Enter the studentÆs name...
Jane
Enter the student's letter grade...
A
Enter the student's letter grade...
B
Enter the student's letter grade...
A
Enter the student's letter grade...
A
Enter the student's letter grade...
A
Enter the student's letter grade...
1
That is not a valid letter grade...
Jane: 3.800000
Enter the student's name...
```

Code I ran....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char StudentName[50];
    char UserInput;
    int GradeSum;
    int TotalGrades;
    float GPA;
    int Test;
    int Try;

    Test = 0;

    while ( Test != 1 )
    {
        printf ("Enter the student’s name...\n");
        scanf ("%49s", StudentName);
        Try = strcmp(StudentName, "");
        if (Try != 0)
        {
            GradeSum = 0;
            TotalGrades = 0;
            GPA = 0;

            while ( Test != 1 )
            {
                printf ("Enter the student’s letter grade...\n");
                scanf (" %c", &UserInput);
                if ((UserInput == 'A') || (UserInput == 'B') || (UserInput == 'C') || (UserInput == 'D') || (UserInput == 'F'))
                {
                    if (UserInput == 'A')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 4;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }
                    else if (UserInput == 'B')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 3;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }
                    else if (UserInput == 'C')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 2;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }
                    else if (UserInput == 'D')
                    {
                        GradeSum += 1;
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }
                    else if (UserInput == 'F')
                    {
                        TotalGrades += 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf ("\nThat is not a valid letter grade...\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            GPA = ((float)GradeSum) / TotalGrades;
            printf ("\n\n%s: %f\n", StudentName, GPA);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set the value of Test, so it will run in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few syntax errors, but my biggest problem was the online compiler I was using.  Plugged the code into a different one that allowed me to enter data real-time and it worked just fine.  Live and learn.